# How to push a named value to a vector in R's cpp11?

Tags: r, r-lib-cpp11

Within R's a package `cpp11`, a named value is pushed to a list as follows:

```
writable::list a;

a.push_back("my_name"_nm = 1);
```

How to do the same if `"my_name"` was stored in the string variable?

Comment: You have the wrong tag here: `Rcpp` is a different package. I'll edit it out.

Comment: My fault. Sorry, Dirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to modify the `"names"` attribute after you have created the list. Here's an example with a function which takes one `int` and one `string` and returns a named list:

```r
library(cpp11)
cpp_function(
    'list one_int_list(int x, std::string list_name) {
    writable::list out;

    out.push_back("tmp_name"_nm = x);

    out.attr("names") =  writable::list(
        { writable::strings({list_name}) }
    );

    return out;
}
'
)

one_int_list(x = 25L, list_name = "some_name")
# $some_name
# [1] 25
```

For a more useful type of list, i.e. one which can have length greater than one, we can take for example [`integers`](https://cpp11.r-lib.org/articles/cpp11.html#vector-input-vector-output) and [`strings`](https://cpp11.r-lib.org/articles/FAQ.html) as input for the values and names respectively:

```r
cpp_function(
    'list long_list(integers x, strings list_names) {

    // Allocate lists for the output and names
    int n = x.size();
    writable::list out;
    writable::list x_names;

    // Push back to those lists
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        out.push_back("tmp"_nm = x[i]);
        x_names.push_back(list_names[i]);
    }

    // Set names attributes
    out.attr("names") = x_names;

    return out;
}
'
)
```

This works in broadly the same way:

```r
long_list(x = c(37L, 42L), list_names = c("name1", "name2"))
# $name1
# [1] 37

# $name2
# [1] 42
```